# Python Matrix, get cordinate from number and opposite

Tags: python, math, matrix, logic, coordinates

#### The Problem:

I have a matrix that has `X` number of columns and `Y` number of rows.

The tiles are labeled from *left to right*, *top to bottom* with numbers in ascending order one by one.

In a **Pythonic**, mathy way, how can I get the coordinates of an N number? How can I get an N number from the coordinates?

---

#### Example:

I have a matrix of `columns(X) = 5` and `row(y) = 6`

So something like this:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
| 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
|  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

---

#### Example code:

```
COLUMN_X = 5
ROW_Y = 6

def cord_to_n(column, row):
    # do the magic
    return n

def n_to_cord(n):
    # do the magic
    return column, row
```

#### The expected output:

```
>>> cord_to_n(2,4) # 2nd column, 4th row
17

>>> n_to_cord(23)
(3,5) # 3rd column, 5th row
```

---

#### Note:

I prefer a solution without using any library, but instead using *python math operators*.

---

#### EDIT

1) This is not my homework or anything, I am self-studying programming and my school does not offer computer science.

2) This was my attempt:

```
def magic(n):
    n = int(n)
    x = n % COLUMN_X # column number
    y = n/ROW_Y + 1 # row number
    return y,x
```

For a while I thought it worked but found out that if the number I am searching for is in the last column it does not work.

Comment: Please add code of what you tried. This is pretty trivial and smells like homework.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Just edited. I already tried it. I also tried to google and this might be even a duplicate question but most likely due to using non-accurate keywords I could not find solution through google.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa This is not a homework as stated in my edit. I am self-studying Python so I rely mainly on free resources online and forum such as stackoverflow.

Comment: Hints: In your attempt, use integer division `//`, not float division `/`, to find `y`. One way to correct your calculation of `x` is to do a conditional: what if the number is in the last column, how can you correct the calculation? Finally, your `return` statement was the values switched.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Does using `//` instead of `/` change anything? As for the return, I know it is switched. I wanted the row first and then the column. As for your suggestion using conditional, I already thought of that, using `if x == 0: x=5` but I thought there would be more 'nicer' way of solving it therefore I put a note there saying: "using python math operators".

Comment: It can be done with only operators by applying a simple fix, but why do you *want* a nicer solution?

Comment: In Python 3, `/` gives a non-integer result, but if you are using Python 2 then `/` works. Another way to find `x` is to do operations on `x-1` then adjust the result. Yet another way is to use [the ternary `if` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/6246044), which is closer to my earlier hint. There are multiple ways to do this--you choose which is best for your situation. I chose my hint to be the one closest to what you had already tried.

Comment: Oops, in my previous comment I meant "do operations on `n-1`..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following small helper will translate every index from your matrix, to its row-col coordinates (based at zero, like python)

**[Edit]** -> If you want the row and col indices starting at one, you can do as follows:

```
row, col = convert_to_base1(get_row_col(idx, rows, cols))
```

following is the code and tests:

```
def convert_to_base1(args):
    row, col = args
    return row + 1, col + 1

def get_row_col(idx, rows, cols):
    """ translates a provided index to its row col coordinates

    idx: int, the index to translate
    rows: int, the number of rows
    cols: int, the number of columns
    """
    ndx = idx - 1
    row = ndx // cols
    col = ndx % cols
    return row, col

def test_get_row_col():
    assert get_row_col(22, 6, 5) == (4, 1)
    assert get_row_col(5, 6, 5) == (0, 4)
    assert get_row_col(6, 6, 5) == (1, 0)
    assert get_row_col(10, 6, 5) == (1, 4)
    assert get_row_col(1, 6, 5) == (0, 0)
    assert get_row_col(11, 6, 5) == (2, 0)
    assert get_row_col(13, 6, 5) == (2, 2)
    assert get_row_col(30, 6, 5) == (5, 4)
    assert get_row_col(26, 6, 5) == (5, 0)

    assert get_row_col(26, 1, 30) == (0, 25)
    assert get_row_col(26, 10, 10) == (2, 5)
    assert get_row_col(26, 7, 4) == (6, 1)
    assert get_row_col(26, 4, 7) == (3, 4)
    print('***all test_get_row_col pass***')

def test_get_row_col_convert_to_base1():
    assert convert_to_base1(get_row_col(22, 6, 5)) == (5, 2)
    assert convert_to_base1(get_row_col(5, 6, 5)) == (1, 5)
    assert convert_to_base1(get_row_col(6, 6, 5)) == (2, 1)
    assert convert_to_base1(get_row_col(10, 6, 5)) == (2, 5)
    assert convert_to_base1(get_row_col(1, 6, 5)) == (1, 1)
    assert convert_to_base1(get_row_col(11, 6, 5)) == (3, 1)
    assert convert_to_base1(get_row_col(13, 6, 5)) == (3, 3)
    assert convert_to_base1(get_row_col(30, 6, 5)) == (6, 5)
    assert convert_to_base1(get_row_col(26, 6, 5)) == (6, 1)

    assert convert_to_base1(get_row_col(26, 1, 30)) == (1, 26)
    assert convert_to_base1(get_row_col(26, 10, 10)) == (3, 6)
    assert convert_to_base1(get_row_col(26, 7, 4)) == (7, 2)
    assert convert_to_base1(get_row_col(26, 4, 7)) == (4, 5)
    print('***all test_get_row_col_convert_to_base1 pass***')


test_get_row_col()
test_get_row_col_convert_to_base1()
```

Comment: The formula for `row` should use `cols` instead of `rows`, i.e.`(idx - 1) // cols + 1`.

Comment: OP's row / column indices start from 1 instead of 0.

Comment: he asked: "In a Pythonic/math way, how can I get the coordinates of an N number? How can I get an N number from the coordinates?"... that's zero base

Comment: I added a wrapper to convert to rows and columns based at 1